# datatables export without all column values from filter

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am using this code to filter the columns in datatables: https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/10/

```
// This code has been beautified via http://jsbeautifier.org/ with 2 spaces indentation.
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cbDropdown(column) {
    return $('<ul>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown'
    }).appendTo($('<div>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown-wrap'
    }).appendTo(column));
  }

  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header()))
          .on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
            var active;
            var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
              active = true;
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();

            // Highlight the current item if selected.
            if (this.checked) {
              $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            } else {
              $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            }

            // Highlight the current filter if selected.
            var active2 = ddmenu.parent().is('.active');
            if (active && !active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().addClass('active');
            } else if (!active && active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().removeClass('active');
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          var // wrapped
            $label = $('<label>'),
            $text = $('<span>', {
              text: d
            }),
            $cb = $('<input>', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              value: d
            });

          $text.appendTo($label);
          $cb.appendTo($label);

          ddmenu.append($('<li>').append($label));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I have the Copy, Excel, and CSV buttons enabled to export data after the view of which data I want is created, but all of the values for the column filtering appear as well.

The default datatables returns only the column headings value on export, which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exportOptions` to filter out the `.cb-dropdown-wrap` element:

```
const exportOptions = {
  format: {
    header: function (data) {
      return $('<div></div>')
        .append(data)
        .find('.cb-dropdown-wrap')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text()
    }
  }   
}
```

In DataTables configuration

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'copyHtml5',
    exportOptions: exportOptions
  },
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    exportOptions: exportOptions
  },
  {
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    exportOptions: exportOptions
  }
]
```

Completely untested, the jsfiddle does not include export at all.

Basically the same as this answer -> [Ignore HTML from header in Jquery Datatables while exporting to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61080060/1407478) so you might say I just could have marked as dupe ...

Comment: Worked liked a charm! Thanks!